Does the PolarDB engine selection of X-Engine not support columnar indexes?
Does the PolarDB engine selection of X-Engine not support columnar indexes?
After selecting the X-Engine for my PolarDB instance and attempting to manage indexes, the following error is displayed:[ERROR] IMCI syntax error: The specified storage engine XENGINE doesn't support in memory columnar index.
